# How to enable scrollbar for this following overlay

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.3

```
el.overlay = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
                                    itemId:'widgetInfoPanel',
                                    html: htmlText,
                                    height: 200,
                                    width: 300,
                                    autoScroll:true,
                                    modal: {
                                        style: 'opacity: 0'
                                    },
                                    hideOnMaskTap:true,
                                    items: [
                                        {
                                            xtype: 'button',
                                            text: "Close".toUpperCase(),
                                            cls: 'button-orange',
                                            listeners: {
                                                tap: function (button) {
                                                    el.overlay.hide();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                });
```

As you can see this is a simple overlay that is created on button click but when the html content is too long it is supposed to show a scrollbar as I have set the autoScroll propoerty to true but I do not see that.

How do i enable that, I am using sencha touch

Comment: Try "scrollable : true" instead of autoScroll.

Comment: @SujataChanda tried that also.. not working. :-(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why are facing this problem, but as @Sujata Chanda suggests by replacing 'autoScroll' to 'scrollable' will solve the problem.

Here is the demo:

- app.js:

  Ext.application({
      name: 'Demo',
      views: ['Main'],

  ```
  launch:function() {
      var mainView = Ext.create('Demo.view.Main');
      //Ext.Viewport.add(mainView);
      var overlay = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
          itemId:'widgetInfoPanel',
          html: 'Hellllllloooojsdghaaaassssasdasdasdasdasdasdasfasfjgasjfasgfjasgfhasgfhjasgfhasgfjhasgfhdgfhjgasfjkagsfadsgfjhkdsagfjkaegfuywegfkjsadgfuwegfjaesgfiouwerhiuwegrowergiuweghfksjdbfsudiyriuweahbrkjewhabfuweyuiwehiuewhiuuuuudhfudsfhdsufjsdhgfuwiaegfdjsbfiuweagiwejhiuewriewougrhoiweuqgioweuagfiuadsgfuagsefwaeygruyaeygsfuaeisdgfaksdjfgkasdjgfksdjagfksjadhfgewuygfjksdhbfuaegsyfajkhsgfuywegfbjkhsaegrou8weybfkuwegr',
          height: 200,
          width: 300,
          scrollable:true,
          modal: {
              style: 'opacity: 0'
          },
          hideOnMaskTap:true,
          items: [
              {
                  xtype: 'button',
                  text: "Close".toUpperCase(),
                  cls: 'button-orange',
                  listeners: {
                      tap: function (button) {
                        overlay.hide();
                      }
                  }
              }
          ]
      });
      Ext.Viewport.add(overlay);
      overlay.show();

  }
  ```

  });

Check this in browser!